# jQuery and Navbar Button

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I been having some troubles involving jQuery and my navbar button.
Let me explain a little more detailed my problem.
So, I made a site using Bootstrap which includes jquery 1.11.2, everything went fine until I decided to use fancybox to create a lightbox with some google maps. (My Google API uses jquery 1.7.1), this is when things started to fail.

I noticed that my Navbar responsive button didn't work whiteout jquery 1.11.2 (which I disabled before) so I put it again but my maps lightbox didn't work.

How can I use jquery 1.7.1 in my navbar? I can't find any codeline with it.
Here's my code for my navbar

```
<!-- Home -->
<section class="header" id="header">
    
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" id="navigation-bar">
        <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://www.ecomotor.cl">Ecomotor</a>
            </div> <!-- /.navbar-header -->


        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#header">Inicio</a></li>
                    
                    <li><a href="#service">Despacho</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#portfolio">Galeria</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">Acerca de</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">Contacto</a></li>
                </ul> <!-- /.nav -->
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div><!-- /.container -->
```

and below is the js used (which has the google API)

```
    <!-- Grab Google CDN's jQuery, fall back to local if offline -->

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/libs/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>      
<!-- FancyBox -->
    <script src="assets/js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/fancybox/jquery.easing-1.3.pack.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/fancybox/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".various").fancybox({
                maxWidth    : 800,
                maxHeight   : 600,
                fitToView   : false,
                width       : '70%',
                height      : '70%',
                autoSize    : false,
                closeClick  : false,
                openEffect  : 'elastic',
                closeEffect : 'none'
            });
        });
    </script>

<script src="assets/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>(if I delete this line, my maps work perfectly but not my navbar button, the opposite happens if I keep it) 
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/contact.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/script.js"></script>
```

Comment: What happens if you remove this line? `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    `

Comment: Maps lightbox doesnt work

Comment: Your first jQuery import is an older version (1.7.1). Could that be the issue? Try 1.11

Comment: i have to use that version for my maps because of Google API, anyways, i tried that and only my navbar works, not my lightbox

Answer (score 0):

## Use a single jQuery version

1. Remove this line:

`<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

2. Remove this line:

`<script src="assets/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>`

3. Put this line before all other `<script>` tags:

`<script src="assets/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>`

This way, you will have only one jQuery version on your page, and this version will be used by both the lightbox and the Navbar responsive button.

## Use two jQuery versions

If you really do need to use two versions of jQuery on your page, that is possible via [**`jQuery.noConflict()`**](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/).

See an example here:

[Can I use multiple versions of jQuery on the same page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566595/can-i-use-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page)

Comment: I did that, my lightbox (probably because this line <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script> has the Google API) didnt work.
Also, my navbar dissapeared.

Comment: is there any way that i can use both on my page ?

Comment: where shoul i put jQuery.noConflict(). on my code ?